# Testing the the truth of the hyperbolic functions on a calculator.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, hyperbolic-functions, calculator

Test the truth of the formula $\cosh ^2 x-\sinh ^2 x=1$ on a calculator  you will probably find that the output changes from 1 to 0 somewhere between $x=10$ and $x=20$. Why is this? Should we conclude that the formula is false in the "real world"?

Comment: No. What we should conclude is that when calculators deal with large numbers there will be rounding errors.

Comment: No calculator is "exact," it is limited by the precision of the machine.

Comment: On some calculators, $(10^{42} + 1) - 10^{42} = 0$.

Comment: Here are results in MS Excel on my smartphone:  11 0.999999881
12 1.000001907
13 0.999992371
14 0.999938965
15 1
16 0.9921875
17 1
18 1
19 0
20 0